# What's the fully active document in HTML5 W3C?

Tags: html, document

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#fully-active

A Document is said to be fully active when it is the active document of its browsing context, and either its browsing context is a top-level browsing context, **or it has a parent browsing context and the Document through which it is nested is itself fully active.**

Because they are nested through an element, child browsing contexts are always tied to a specific Document in their parent browsing context. User agents must not allow the user to interact with child browsing contexts of elements that are in Documents that are not themselves fully active.

---

I can't understand above bold texts (which is started with "or it has a parent...").

Let me explain, plz.

---

1)top-level browsing context

-2)document of the top-level browsing context

--3)child browsing context (iframe)

---4)active document of the child browsing context

----5)grandchild browsing context (iframe's iframe)

then, 4) is a fully active document?

Comment: Think of a document in an iframe.

Comment: 5) is irrelevant. 2) the document must be the active document.